# Funções dentro de funções em Python

Tags: python, funções

Estou criando um script em python para obtenção de dados de minha empresa...
basicamente estruturei o codigo da seguinte forma:

```
from main import driver, get_store_name, id_lojas, get_store_url_consume, login
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


    def verify_per_day(store, month, day):
    
        workers_dict_with_consume_amount = {}
    
        if month < 10:
            month = f"{month:02}"
    
        if day < 10:
                day = f"{day:02}"
        
    
        def get_month_to_check():
    
            get_store_url_consume(id_lojas[f"{store}"], month, day)
    
        def get_workers_name():
    
            work_select_element_in_page = driver.find_element(By.ID, "Funcionario_'121'" )
    
            list_of_workers_names_by_select = Select(work_select_element_in_page).options
    
            list_of_workers = []
    
            for name in list_of_workers_names_by_select:
                if name.text == "(Escolha Funcionario)":
                    pass
                else:
                    list_of_workers.append(name.text)
    
            return list_of_workers
            
    
        def update_dict_with_worker_key(worker):
            workers_dict_with_consume_amount.update({f"{worker}": []})
    
    
            return workers_dict_with_consume_amount    
        
        def get_consume_amount(worker):
            
            def iter_over_tbody_andget_consume_by_worker():
                tbody_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="registos-diario-consumos-funcionarios-grid"]/table/tbody')
                
                tr_elements = tbody_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    
                slice_consume_amount = 0
                garlic_bread_consume_amount = 0
    
                for tr_line in tr_elements:
    
                    # cada linha tr tem o nome do funcionario, se a linha conter o nome, pegue o td com index = 4
    
                    td_elements = tr_line.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    
                    """
                    td_elemtets retorna uma lista com todos os elementos(TD) da linha (TR)
                    index 1 corresponde ao funcionario
                    index 4 corresponde a quantidade de consumo
    
                    """
                    try:
                        if f"{worker}" == td_elements[1].text and td_elements[3].text == "Fatia Funcionário":
    
                            slice_worker_consume = td_elements[4].text
    
                            slice_consume_amount += int(slice_worker_consume)
    
                        elif f"{worker}" == td_elements[1].text and td_elements[3].text == "Pão de Alho":
                            garlic_bread_consume_consume = td_elements[4].text
    
                            garlic_bread_consume_amount += int(garlic_bread_consume_consume)
    
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
                return [slice_consume_amount, garlic_bread_consume_amount]
            return iter_over_tbody_andget_consume_by_worker()
        
        def add_consume_to_each_worker(worker_name, consume):
            workers_dict_with_consume_amount[f"{worker_name}"] = consume
    
        def run():
           # 1 checar este mes
           get_month_to_check()
    
           workers_names = get_workers_name()
           
           # 2 para cada trabalhador que for encontrado
           for worker in workers_names:
               
               update_dict_with_worker_key(worker) #atualiza o dict com o novo trabalhador
    
               amount = get_consume_amount(worker) #chama a funcao responsavel por pegar a quantidade de consumo desse trabalhador
    
               add_consume_to_each_worker(worker, amount) #adiciona ao valor da chave[worker] o valor do consumo = amount
        run()
        
        return workers_dict_with_consume_amount
    
    login()
    
    store = get_store_name()
    
    for day in range(1, 32):
        for worker, consume in verify_per_day(store, 9, day).items():
            if consume[0] >= 3:
                print(f"{worker} esta consumindo mais do que o permitido({consume[0]}) no dia {day}, pao de alho : {consume[1]}")
```

Ter essas funções dentro da função principal na minha visao ajuda a manter, mas ate que ponto isso se torna necessario?

Answer (score -3):

Ter as funções todas dentro de uma função. Não e errado para código, imagino que esteja funcionando. O problema quando esse seu código começar evoluir e dar muitos problemas. Por isso existe estudos e livros para escrever códigos legiveis e organizados para evitar problemas futuros, sendo assim o seu código está ruim. Primeiro uma função deve  fazer apenas uma função, assim quando for aplicar testes, vai existir um teste apenas uma determinada função, em seguida quando for debugar o seu código, a função estando separada realizando apenas uma tarefa vai ficar mais fácil de solucionar. Eu recomendo você ler novamente a documentação ou comprar um curso para visualizar que existe formas mais práticas para construir um código legivel. Isso vai salvar você no futuro.